# Ubuntu really slow to shutdown/restart

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, virtualization

I'm running ubuntu 14.04.4 as a VM on Hyper-V (Server 2012 R2). The VM is configured to only have 1 VCPU and 2GB fixed ram.

Shutting down, or restarting takes around 15 minutes (sometimes a lot longer). The terminal disconnects immediately, and I can't reconnect but other than that nothing appears to happen. Connecting to the VM (I think it's called tty1, but I'm very new to linux!) I can see this:

[image: Restart ending at Restoring Resolver State]

In Hyper-V the state goes to "Stopping-Critical" and the status is "In Service". Eventually the machine wills top.

I've had a look around the issue but I'm struggling to find any obvious issue (I also can't tell if Hyper-V is causing the issue or not).

I think I might need to do something with grub to show me more info, but I'm a little out of my depth here! Any advice would be really useful!

[EDIT]

After rebooting another ubuntu machine running on the hyper-v server I can see it's having the same issues. I'm going to move the machine to another hyper-v server and see if that is the issue, but at the minute I suspect it is.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was an issue with Hyper-V. Removing and re-adding the feature fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

If you can change Hypervisor host server, I'll recommend you the free [Citrix XenServer](https://www.citrix.com/products/xenserver/overview.html), the Hyper-V is rather used to be hosted on Win Servers running Win VMs.
Maybe OpenStack, KVM or even VmWare could be a better Hypervisor choice...

In this case, the drivers might not be installed. Look at `dmesg | less`, or `less /var/log/messages` from Hyper-V console (tty#), after you was ordered a shutdown.

Comment: @Fabby what in the world are you saying that for.. Don't think an answer is good then downvote. Your delete vote privilege is not for answers you dislike..